# How to create Gradient with more than three colors using XML

Tags: android, gradient

I need to create a linear Gradient with 5 different colors. 
I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/diagramBlueColor"
                        android:endColor="@color/diagramGreenColor"
                        android:type="linear"
                        android:angle="0" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/diagramGreenColor"
                        android:endColor="@color/diagramYellowColor"
                        android:type="linear"
                        android:angle="0" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/diagramYellowColor"
                        android:endColor="@color/diagramOrangeColor"
                        android:type="linear"
                        android:angle="0" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/diagramOrangeColor"
                        android:endColor="@color/diagramRedColor"
                        android:type="linear"
                        android:angle="0" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But every shape is overriding the shape before. I need to create the gradient using xml. How can i do that?

If it is not possible with pure xml then how can i do it in java code?
I tried this:

```
/**
 *
 * @return
 */
public static PaintDrawable getColorScala() {
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory shaderFactory = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
                    new int[] {
                            0xFF1e5799,
                            0xFF207cca,
                            0xFF2989d8,
                            0xFF207cca }, //substitute the correct colors for these
                    new float[] {
                            0, 0.40f, 0.60f, 1 },
                    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            return linearGradient;
        }
    };

    PaintDrawable paint = new PaintDrawable();
    paint.setShape(new RectShape());
    paint.setShaderFactory(shaderFactory);

    return paint;
}
```

But when i set the background of my view:

```
view.setBackground(Colors.getColorScala());
```

The background of my view is white. I want it to look like that:

[image]

Comment: you cannot do that in pure xml, you need to do it in java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as you already found. Lookup you colors to make it more flexible in code i think is the best way to do so

```
getColor(R.color.rainbow_1);
getColor(R.color.rainbow_2);
getColor(R.color.rainbow_3);
getColor(R.color.rainbow_4);
getColor(R.color.rainbow_5);
```

and create your array

Comment: it still does not work. the drawable returned is still white.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your colors via getColor from colors.xml or parse it..

```
int[] gradientColors = new int[] {
        Color.parseColor("#80E1F1"),
        Color.parseColor("#5257F6"),
        Color.parseColor("#8222FC")
};

float[] gradientColorPos = new float[] {
        0, 0.5f, 1f
};
```

use it like so..

```
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height, gradientColors, gradientColorPos, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```